# Where to download Mono 3.8? (installer, not sources)

Tags: macos, mono

Because of a [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=21135) in Mono 3.10, I have to revert to Mono 3.8.

Where can Mono 3.8 be downloaded?

At http://www.mono-project.com/download/ only 3.10 is available for download.
At https://github.com/mono/mono/releases only the source is available for download, not binaries.
There is a link to older changelogs, but not to older binaries.

Mac OS X, also Linux if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Here we go, there's all the files you might need: http://download.mono-project.com/archive/

Comment: Beat me to it. +1